# how is this code reversed and updated without pop and push?

Tags: javascript

I'm introducing myself in javascript and I am in this part of eloquent javascript where an array is reversed,

[demo[added console.log]](https://repl.it/Cciw/2)

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(array.length / 2); i++) {
    var old = array[i];
    array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
    array[array.length - 1 - i] = old;
    console.log(old);
  }
  return array;
}
var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
// → [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

I thought the var old was updated but I think it's not[from console.log], it's the same on the first old on the console. I tried to manipulate for loop with i<1; and it still reversed 5 and 1.

My question is, how is this loops reversed? with specificity in this lines of code

```
var old = array[i];
array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
array[array.length - 1 - i]= old;
```

An example demo will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is swapping elements of the array.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var temp = array[0]; // 1
array[0] = array[4]; // array is now [5, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array[4] = temp; // array is now [5, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```

Now you can imagine repeating this with `array[1]` and `array[3]`, etc. to fully reverse the array. That's what your code is doing.

Adding some logging might help to further visualize what's happening:

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
  var limit = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
  console.log('Limit is ' + limit);
  for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    console.log('Looping with i = ' + i);
    console.log('Array starting as ' + array);

    var old = array[i];
    array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
    array[array.length - 1 - i] = old;
    
    console.log('Array after swap: ' + array);
    
    console.log('\n');
  }

  console.log('Done!');

  return array;
}

var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
```